# Delete operation in Binary Search tree

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have written this delete function to delete a node in a binary search tree. The problem is it deletes the root node of the key itself. Tried Debugging but not clear whats wrong with it.

Also I don't understand why are we setting this `node->m_left=deletenode(data,node->m_left);`

```
#include "node.h"
#include <queue>

template<class T>
class bst
{
private:
    Node<T>* root;

public:
    bst()
    {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    ~bst()
    {
        deletree(root);
    }

    Node<T>* gethead()
    {
        return this->root;
    }

    void addnode(Node<T>* node, T data)
    {
        if (this->root == nullptr) {
            Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
            this->root = new_node;
        }
        else if (data > node->m_data) {
            if (node->m_right != nullptr) {
                addnode(node->m_right, data);
            }
            else {
                Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                node->m_right = new_node;
            }
        }
        else if (data < node->m_data) {
            if (node->m_left != nullptr) {
                addnode(node->m_left, data);
            }
            else {
                Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                node->m_left = new_node;
            }
        }
    }

    void addnode(T data)
    {
        addnode(this->root, data);
    }

    Node<T>* deletenode(T data, Node<T>* node)
    {
        //base case
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        if (data < node->m_data) {
            node->m_left = deletenode(data, node->m_left);
        }
        if (data > node->m_data) {
            node->m_right = deletenode(data, node->m_right);
        }

        if (node->m_left == nullptr && node->m_right == nullptr) {
            node = nullptr;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: It will help you (and others) immeasurably to use consistent code layout.  If you are lazy and just do whatever, your life becomes harder.  I have run your code through an auto-layout, and performed a few other tidy-ups to achieve basic readability.

Comment: I am not expert in data structures. But your tree looks similar to a Merkle tree. Maybe [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/52811) can help

Comment: "Also I don't understand why are we setting this" Start by understanding this part. The reason is because in general you might have the subtree rebalanced due of the deletion of a node, so the root of the subtree might change. You can easily see this by imagining that the key is just in the root of your - let's say - left subtree. In this case deletenode would return `nullptr` and the whole subtree is lost. The right way would be to have deletenode return the new root of the subtree after making a new subtree from left and right parts. See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree